# Views - D7 - Filtering by authorname only works with admin role

Tags: views, ajax

I've created a view which is displaying time tracking information.  Everything works great except one thing and I can't figure out what the issue is.  I have an exposed filter which filters by authorname.  The filter by default is an autocomplete text field.  When I am logged in as an admin role, the autocomplete works as it should, however when I am logged in as an authenticated user, that filter stops working.  All my other exposed filters work, except this one.  I am assuming it is a permissions issue, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what I need to enable to allow a regular user use this filter.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I am using D7 with Views.

Comment: is `Access: Permission | View published content` in your Views Page settings

Comment: it may be the "View user profiles" permission?

Comment: The permission "view published content" and also "View user profiles" have been checked off.  I realized after that the autocomplete is actually showing up, however, unlike the admin user, the autocomplete suggestion drop down shows up near the top of the page.  So I wasn't seeing it because it was showing up off the page.  It's weird.  As an admin, this doesn't happen.  Also I am using a standard Bartik theme with no modifications as I am in a testing state.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed the Administration Views module and ran into this issue.  Setting the "View user profiles" permission fixed the problem.  Thanks @Marius Ilie.